# An array that is a max heap, but whose reverse is not a min heap?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, heapsort

I have a question that I believe I understand, but am looking for some verification. I know that in order to be a min heap, the child must be greater than the parent, and in order to be a max heap, the parent must be greater than the child. If so, is this a valid answer to the following question:

Create an array with 5 elements, that is a max heap, but whose reverse is not a min heap.

A = [ 100, 50, 49, 40, 41 ]

```
    100
  |     |
  50     49
 |  |
40  41
```

So, just verifying, that if I read this tree as a min heap, I'd read 40, 41, 50, 49, 100? Thank you - this confuses me and any insight into Heaps would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple counterexample:
Consider `A = [10 7 3 6 5]` - array is valid max-heap.

```
     10
   |     |
  7      3
 |  |
 6  5
```

But reverse `B = [5 6 3 7 10]` is not min-heap

So not all reverses of max-heap arrays are mean-heaps